# Correct Use of the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Please check if this proof is correct. Thank you for your help!

**Let $f(x) = \frac{20}{x^6 + x^4 + x^2 +1}$.**

Show that for any $k$ element of $(0,5]$

there is a point c greater than or equal to $1$ such that $f(c) = k$.

**Proof.**

$f(x)$ is continuous everywhere because its denominator is never equal to $0$ and the numerator is always equal to $20$.

Also, $c$ is element of $[1, \infty )$ and notice that $k$ lies between $f(1) = 5$ and the limit of $f(x)$ when $n$ goes to infinite (the limit equals to $0$).

**Thus, according to the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a value $c$ element of**

**$[1, \infty)$ such that**

**$f(c) = \frac{20}{c^6+c^4+c^2+1} = k$,**

**for all $k$ element of $(0,5]$. Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks correct. Alternatively, you could look at the polynomial $p(x)=x^6+x^4+x^2+1$, where $p(x)\geq1, \forall x$. It's a

- continuous function
- and $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} p(x) = +\infty$

according to the [definition of the limit at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_involving_infinity), we have that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0:p(x)>\epsilon$ when $x>\delta$.

Now we can use Intermediate Value Theorem on this polynomial, because $p(0)=1$ and (according to the limit) for any $k_0>1$ there will be plenty of $x_{k_0}$ such that $p(x_{k_0})>k_0>p(0)$. Particularly, $\forall k_0\geq4$ there $\exists c$ such that $p(c)=k_0=\frac{20}{k}$, where $k \in (0, 5]$. Thus $k=\frac{20}{p(c)}=f(c)$.

Comment: Very original idea! I never thought about it! Thank you so much!

Comment: One question about my proof. I used the limit of f(x), but the theorem requires that the function at that point be defined. Is my trick legal?

Comment: That's why I used the polynomial, to make it more obvious. Also, in this case, you can suppose that $\exists k$ such that $\forall c, f(c) \neq k$ or $\epsilon_0=|f(c) - k| > \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} > 0$ which will lead to a contradiction, due to the nature of function $f(x)$

Comment: Thank you again for your brilliant ideas! Just confirm if I understood correctly. My trick was legal or not?

Comment: I have other doubt. in your proof you used p(x) but you did not verify the conditions of the Intermediate Value Theorem. I am talking about a, b, p(a), p(b). p(a)>p(b) or viceversa. Am I wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: I assumed the facts that $p(x)$ is continuous, ascending as $p'(x)>0, \forall x>0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty } p(x)=+\infty $

Comment: I edited my answer, please let me know if it's still confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now your proof is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

your above proof is correct

fred

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: One question about my proof. I used the limit of f(x), but the theorem requires that the function at that point be defined. Is my trick legal?